# How to idle file-processing program until new data arrives in the file

Tags: python, parsing, eof

i have a text file that is being written by another program every 10 seconds.
my code goes through this file and parses the data i want. but at some point the for loop reaches the end of file and program closes.

GOAL: i want the program to wait inside the for loop for more data to come so that it parses the new data too.

i tried it using a while with a condition about the lines that are left to be read but for some reason the program just stops a little after exiting the while loop.if i add let's say 25 lines...it processes 9 of them and then the program exits the for loop and program finishes(not crashes)

QUESTION: is there a better way to idle the program until new data arrives? what is wrong in this code?

```py
k = -1
with open('epideiksh.txt') as weather_file:
    for line in weather_file:
            k = k+1
            lines_left = count_lines_of('epideiksh.txt') - k
            while ( lines_left <= 10 ):
                print("waiting for more data")
                time.sleep(10)
                pointer = count_lines('epideiksh.txt') - k              
            if line.startswith('Heat Index'):
                do_my_thing()  
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: How does `count_lines_of` work? Why do you sleep when there are still 10 lines left? Is `pointer = count_lines` a holdover from an earlier version, or what? When you say "stops a little after exiting the while loop", which while loop are you referring to? If it's the outer one, why shouldn't it stop?

Comment: pointer was left by mistake. it's lines_left which i forgot to rename. it's lines_left = count_lines('epideiksh.txt') - k.
there's only one while loop. the outer out is a for loop. count_lines_of() is a function i wrote that counts the total lines of the file. 10 was arbitrary. i just picked a small number near the end of file

Comment: So you're reading the whole file every time you read a line (and possibly more often). That seems a tad inefficient :)

Comment: I don't know why your code exhibits that behaviour; I suspect that it's because the file iterator buffers input, and so EOF is being encountered in the for loop, even though you're not yet at that point. But that's just a guess. I provided an answer with some indication on how to tail.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest, but slightly error-prone way of simulating `tail` is:

```
with open("filename") as input:
  while True:
    for line in input:
      if interesting(line):
        do_something_with(line)
    sleep a_little
    input.seek(0, io.SEEK_CUR)
```

In my very limited testing, that seemed to work without the seek. But it shouldn't, since normally you have to do something like that in order to clear the eof flag. One thing to keep in mind is that tell() cannot be used on a (text) file while it is being iterated, and seeking from SEEK_CUR invokes tell(). So in the above code snippet, you could not `break` out of the `for` loop and fall into the `input.seek()` call.

The problem with the above is that it is possible that the `readline` (implicit in the iterator) will only read part of the line currently being written. So you need to be prepared to abandon and reread partial lines:

```
with open("filename") as input:
  # where is the end of the last complete line read
  where = input.tell()
  # use readline explicitly because next() and tell() are incompatible
  while True:
    line = input.readline()
    if not line or line[-1] != '\n':
      time.sleep(a_little)
      input.seek(where)
    else: 
      where = input.tell()
      if interesting(line):
        do_something_with(line)
```